# Call to a member function connection() on null (After upgrading Laravel Homestead)

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I updated my Homestead box from the 20.04 repo to the latest official release. Everything installed fine and seems to work correctly but my app is completely broken now. I have upgraded Homestead in the past without any issues.

Any command I run comes back with:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function connection() on null in /home/vagrant/code/REMOVED/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1498
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vagrant/code/REMOVED/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1464): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::resolveConnection()
#1 /home/vagrant/code/REMOVED/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1271): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getConnection()
#2 /home/vagrant/code/REMOVED/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1188): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newBaseQueryBuilder()
#3 /home/vagrant/code/REMOVED/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1224): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newModelQuery()
#4 /home/vagrant/code/REMOVED/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1177): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQueryWithoutScopes()
#5 /home/vagrant/code/REMOVED in /home/vagrant/code/REMOVED/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 1498
```

I cannot run any artisan command nor can Composer finish creating proper autoload files.

Browsing to the web infarface shows:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ComposerAutoloaderInit4ae805320ff6a78bd9cc38b042c51006::getLoader() in /home/vagrant/code/REMOVED/vendor/autoload.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /home/vagrant/code/REMOVED/bootstrap/autoload.php(3): require_once() #1 /home/vagrant/code/REMOVED/public/index.php(34): require_once('/home/vagrant/c...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/vagrant/code/REMOVED/vendor/autoload.php on line 7
```

MariaDB is running, still using the default homestead/secret user and pass. The .env and all code are identical to before the upgrade too. Also still using PHP 7.4 in both nginx and CLI.

I have no clue what to do or where to look. Any ideas?

[EDIT]

I have enabled the MariaDB General Log to see incoming connection attempts but Laravel does not even try to connect, so it's not a DB issue.

Comment: And what is the code in line 1498 of that file? Are we meant to _guess_ ?

Comment: Well it is in the vendor folder so that is a stock Laravel file....   https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v8.40.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1498

Comment: Are you able to run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @waterloomatt It does kind of run but then fails afterwards because composer.json is configured to run some artisan commands like "php artisan package:discover --ansi"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out partially. Linux did not show the entire error, when I ran the artisan command on my Mac locally it pointed  to some package  trying to execute a DB query to grab a setting value.

For some unknown reason that failed. I removed the line and everything ran smoothly. Cached .env, ran dump-auto and restarted FPM and everything worked for 1 page load.

All subsequent page loads throw a PHP error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ComposerAutoloaderInit4d864c59644e635478404aa0440854b7::getLoader() in /home/vagrant/code/REMOVED/vendor/autoload.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /home/vagrant/code/REMOVED/bootstrap/autoload.php(3): require_once() #1 /home/vagrant/code/REMOVED/public/index.php(34): require_once('/home/vagrant/c...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/vagrant/code/REMOVED/vendor/autoload.php on line 7
```